# How to Resend HTTP Request With 2FA Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coinbase-api

I'm following Coinbase's guide on sending bitcoin to someone via the API. Coinbase requires user to enter 2FA code when `sendMoney()` is called. Then I somehow need to put this code in the HTTP header for `sendMoney()` to successfully execute. But I'm not sure how to make this work with Coinbase's API (`sendMoney()` has no parameter for setting the HTTP header). I think I could manually POST to URL instead of calling `sendMoney()`, but I'm not sure what parameters to pass.

```
function getBalance(client, res){
    client.getAccount('BTC', function(err,account){
        // SENDING MONEY REQUIRES 2FA
        account.sendMoney({
            'to': '3MLCRpMDXC3AFBsaSLNimWfJFvsMVBq4Ac',
            'amount': '0.0000018',
            'currency': 'BTC'
        }, function(err, txt){
            res.render('authPurchase'); // RENDER INPUT FIELD FOR USER TO ENTER 2FA CODE
        });
    });
} // how do I 'replay' the above sendMoney request with the 2FA code in the http header?
```

Coinbase Docs provide this walkthrough, but sadly no example pertaining to making a POST request with 2FA authorization.

```
1. User is sending funds and the app calls POST api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/primary/transactions
2. Server responds with 402 and sends the user a 2FA token via SMS if he doesn’t have Authy installed
3. App re-plays the request from step 1 with exactly same parameters and the 2FA token in the CB-2FA-TOKEN header (HOW????)
4. Transaction is sent and 201 CREATED status code is returned
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

```
module.exports.replaySendMoney = function replaySendMoney(smsCode){
    // in the future access token will be stored and retrieved from database
    var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
    let accessToken = '2aac7a723eb58bfaf13a9073ac7b6982dca072f14fa0abbc766e9ed9f60be596';
    let refreshToken = '17a609e13c7608ecd499a1be502da19a7095ccf2d5fe9f40fca2b87501f7c233';
    var client = new Client({'accessToken': accessToken, 'refreshToken': refreshToken});
    client.getAccount('BTC', function(err,acct){
                // REQUIRES 2FA
        acct.sendMoney({
            'to': '3MLCRpMDoC3AFBsbSLNimWfJFvsMVBq4Ac',
            'amount': '0.0000018',
            'currency': 'BTC',
            'two_factor_token' : smsCode
        }, function(err, txt){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(txt);
            res.render('authPurchase', {});
        });
    });
}
```